# Pylint can't find type alias defined inside a class definition. Bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I have something like the following:

```
import typing

class MyClass:
    Things = typing.Sequence[str]

    def use_things(self, o: Things) -> None:
        pass

    def get_things(self) -> Things:
        pass
```

And pylint says "Things" for the return type of get_things() is undefined.  However, it seems to find it just fine in the signature for use_things().  Is this a bug in my code or in pylint?

Comment: Can you give your actual error ? Copy past what `pylint` command return.

Comment: t1.py:9: [undefined-variable (E0602)] Undefined variable 'Things'